# Here open ball are intersecting with the curve,,,then why they are not locally connected....??

Tags: general-topology

Why topologist sine curve  not locally connected ?

i was  thinking  about this  problem,,,and i was googling and found this answer  here..

[Why is the "topologist's sine curve" not locally connected?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/667117/Here)

But  i didn't  understand as  not getting  in my head..

as  i have  thinking my ownself[image]

Here  open  ball are  intersecting  with the  curve,,,then  why  they  are not  locally connected....

Comment: The point is that to go (along the curve) from one point on the curve near $(0,0)$ to another, you may need to go all the way to $y=1$ or $-1$ and back, thus going outside your ball.

Comment: @RobertIsrael..thanks u